# Scriptural verses that mention whether sleeping during the day is a sin or has negative consequences

Tags: scripture, upanishads, sin, reference-request, surya

I am currently reading the Prashna Upanisad. [Verse 1.5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/prashna-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145280.html) reveals that the sun is associated with prana:

> > आदित्यो ह वै प्राणो रयिरेव चन्द्रमा रयिर्वा एतत्सर्वं यन्मूर्तं चामूर्तं च तस्मान्मूर्तिरेव रयिः ॥ ५ ॥ 
> > **ādityo ha vai prāṇo** rayireva candramā rayirvā etatsarvaṃ yanmūrtaṃ cāmūrtaṃ ca tasmānmūrtireva rayiḥ || 5 ||
> > 5.**The sun is life**, indeed, and the moon, the food; all this having form and formless is food; so form is certainly food.

[Verse 1.13](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/prashna-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145288.html) reveals that those who spill semen during the day, the time period when the sun is visible in the sky, waste life:

> > अहोरात्रो वै प्रजापतिस्तस्याहरेव प्राणो रात्रिरेव रयिः प्राणं वा एते प्रस्कन्दन्ति । ये दिवा रत्या संयुज्यन्ते ब्रह्मचर्यमेव तद्यद्रात्रौ रत्या संयुज्यन्ते ॥ १३ ॥
> > ahorātro vai prajāpatistasyāhareva **prāṇo rātrireva rayiḥ prāṇaṃ vā ete praskandanti** | ye divā ratyā saṃyujyante brahmacaryameva tadyadrātrau ratyā saṃyujyante || 13 ||
> > 13.The day and night is, indeed, the lord of creation. Of that, the day is the prana and the night, indeed, is the food. **Those who combine with Rati (sexual intercourse) by day, spill prana**. That they combine with Rati by night is Brahmacharyam indeed.

I was wondering if those who sleep during the day, the period when the sun is out, waste prana and lose longevity and health. The two verses from the Prashna Upanishad reveal that the sun is associated with prana and seem to suggest that those who do wasteful things during the day, the time of prana, lose prana. Are there any scriptural verses that directly support/disprove my ponderings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Manu Smriti 7.47](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200711.html) explains that sleeping in the day (i.e., when the sun is out) is sinful

> Hunting, dice, **sleeping during the day**, censoriousness, women, intoxication, musical triad and listless wandering constitute the ten-fold set arising from the love of pleasure.—(47).
>
> Medhātithi’s commentary:
> ‘Sleeping during the day’.—i.e., not acting at the time at which a certain action should be done. The term ‘divā’ here does not stand for the day only; this same idea being expressed elsewhere by means of the phrase ‘sleeping at the time of waking.’
>
> Or, the term may betaken in its literal sense; sleeping during the day is positively prohibited, and it stands in the way of all business. This habit causes disappointment to men who want an interview with the king, and also to others; and as such becomes, a source of discontent among the people..

[Here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199697.html) is another relevant verse.